# Finding Pairs Divisible by $K$ in Array

Tags: number-theory

Given array of integers $arry=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$ and a divisor $k=5$. If we want to find pairs  of numbers where there sum are divisible by $k$, we can use the following example to illustrate how we can derive a rule to find all pairs:

$1 \bmod{5} = 1$. Then, when we reach number 4 in the array, we can find that $4 \bmod{5} = 4$ and the complement of the mod is $5-4=1$ is already calculated, which means we find a pair $(1, 4)$ that have a sum divisible by 5.

**Question**: Can you please show if there is a mathematical rule/fact used here to conclude that if the complement of a number mod already calculated as in the case above, then we conclude that this is a pair divisible by the $k$. Hopefully my question is clear. Please let me know if I should add more details.